# iOS App Extension has PFUser currentUser set to nil

Tags: ios, parse-platform, ios8, ios-app-extension

I have a Parse-enabled iOS 8 app and I'm trying to enable Share Extension. I've done *exactly* what it says at https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#extensions but in my app extension, `[PFUser currentUser]` is set to `nil` (while it is not nil in my app), and `[PFInstallation currentInstallation]` is set to a new instance instead of my existing installation. There seems to be a problem with App Extension communicating with my app.

In the Parse docs it clearly states:

> If you have an existing app using the Parse SDK, when users upgrade to
>   your latest app version (with data sharing enabled), the Parse SDK
>   will automatically move the main app's local persistent data (Local
>   Datastore, current PFUser, current PFInstallation, etc) from the app's
>   sandbox container to the shared container.

I have enabled Keychain Sharing and App Groups with the same IDs, and added the appropriate code. Why am I still getting `nil` as the current user in my extension? I am on the latest Parse iOS SDK (1.7.4).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the problem:

I wasn't enabling local datastore in the app extension. Data store must be enabled both in the app itself *and* the app extension. Adding `[Parse enableLocalDatastore];` before initializing Parse and after data sharing code (`enableDataSharingWithApplicationGroupIdentifier:containingApplication:`) solved my problem.