# To keep the current user logged in using swift and parse

Tags: ios, swift, ios7, authentication, parse-platform

I'm trying to keep the current user logged in even if they close the app(no minimize but close) like every other app. Parse documentation suggests using

```
var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
if currentUser != nil {
  // Do stuff with the user
} else {
  // Show the signup or login screen
}
```

But the currentUser is always nil after closing the app. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30429294/ios-app-extension-has-pfuser-currentuser-set-to-nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That snippet of code should work as long as the session in parse is still up.

I ran into the same problem because I wrote that code inside of func viewDidLoad().

When i wrote:

```
func viewDidAppear(animated:Bool){
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    if currentUser != nil {
        // Do stuff with the user
    } else {
        // Show the signup or login screen
    }
```

it worked perfectly fine